# My AJAX login form in codeigniter always chooses the else statement, even if the conditions are met. How to solve these?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So I looked all across google and stackoverflow to find solution for this problem, but hadn't seen a specific solution. So here's the problem:

Everytime I submit my login form, whether credentials is correct or incorrect, ajax request always chooses the else statement.

Here's my HTML code and Ajax request.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-section" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <img id="logoonly" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/cslogo5.png" />
            </div>

                    <form action="#" id="frm_login" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">


                            <div id="error_msg" class="alert alert-danger" class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center; display: none">
                               Incorrect Student number or Password.
                            </div>

                        <label for="numbers" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Student No.</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input name="stud_id" id="stud_id" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Student No." required="required" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input name="password" id="password "type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" data-toggle="password" required="required"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer" >
                        <p style="float: left; position: absolute; margin-top: 13px"><font size="1">Copyright 2017 &copy BulSU CS Online Portal.</font>
            </p>
                            <a type="submit" value="Login" ><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="login_btn">Submit</button></a>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" >Clear</button>
                    </div>

                    </form>

        </div>
    </div>



</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#frm_login').submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('user/do_login'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: $("#stud_id").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
            },
            success:function(data)
            {

                if(data== 'Yes')
                {
                    alert("Success!");
                }
                else if(data== 'No')
                {
                    $('.alert').show().fadeIn("400");
                }
            },
        });
    });
}); 
    </script>
```

Here's my controller

```
public function do_login() {

    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $students = $this->db->get_where("student", array("stud_id ="=>$_POST['username'],"password ="=>$_POST['password']))->result();

        if(empty($students))
        {
            echo "No";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Yes";
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax passes the if statement and always chooses the else condition in my Ajax code.

I tried removing ajax, my code is working, I think my problem is with Ajax's condition. I think I just incorrectly written some code, of I lacking a simple line of code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure  `do_login`  giving yes as a response? try `console.log(data)`  and check what is output

Comment: Where should I put console.log(data)?

Comment: inside `success:function(data){`  and try to check by providing fasle data and correct data input (login credentials)

Comment: If you have HASHED the password when you store it on that database... Your query wont ever find the user as you are trying to match it with a PLAIN TEXT password entered by the user on the page

Comment: My password isn't hashed on my database, I tried removing the ajax jquery and the code in my controller works, it passes the condition Yes and No. However when I put the ajax jqeury back, it just returns always as No.

Comment: Im sorry @Anant but where exactly should I put console.log(data)?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller try like this..

1.Use `$this->input->post()` instead of `$_POST[]` in codeigniter.

2.Your array inside where condition is wrong.So

**Change**

```
array("stud_id ="=>$_POST['username'],"password ="=>$_POST['password']);//remove = when from keys of your array
```

**TO**

```
array("stud_id"=>$this->input->post('username'),"password"=>$this->input->post('password'))
```

Finally

```
public function do_login() {

    if(isset($this->input->post('username')))
    {
        $students = $this->db->get_where("student", array("stud_id"=>$this->input->post('username'),"password"=>$this->input->post('password')))->result();

        if(count($students)>0)
        {
            echo "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but now ajax only reads the IF statement, won't execute my else if statement.

Comment: Is your password field being hashed before you save it?

Comment: Also dont forget to load `url` helper because you are using `base_url()`.

Comment: Well at least you saw my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277656/my-ajax-login-form-in-codeigniter-always-chooses-the-else-statement-even-if-the#comment71711988_42277656) even of @PatrickBryanTorres did not

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes agree with you.Also passed array is wrong.

Comment: I'm so sorry @RiggsFolly haha. I tried ur code and it does the same with my former code. I also double checked my model if there is a code hashing my password I'm very sure it isn't. As I said earlier, whenever I remove my ajax request, the controller works fine, I think my mistake is in the ajax jquery, I just don't know which one

Comment: see in your console using `console.log(data)` inside ajax's success function.what you get in console?

Comment: Im sorry but where exactly should I put this code? I already put it inside success but nothing happens

Comment: Im sorry sir @Hekmat but where exactly should I put console.log(data)?

Comment: inside ajax's success functon.inspect element and see in console tab.

Comment: It says "no" which is the result if the login credentials are incorrect, however it still says "no" even my credentials are correct :( @Hekmat

Answer (score -1):

Your form is storing the username as 'stud_id':

```
<input name="stud_id" ...>
```

But in your controller your trying to get from the post 'username':

```
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
```

Just change that line to use the same value you used in the form:

```
    if(isset($_POST['stud_id']))
```

Comment: he is sending form through `ajax`.see this line `username: $("#stud_id").val();`.

Comment: I already changed it, I been trying every configuration just to make it work but it does not. :(